# Form in a dynamic HTML table

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I am trying to create a HTML table, with a 2 fields on each row for the user to fill in (sports matches predictions). It loads data from one table(List) and should write into another one (Predictions)
Right now I have a cycle which loops through the matches and based on that creates the HTML table.

**input.html**

```
{% block body %}
    <form method="post">

        {% csrf_token %}        
        <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <th>Round</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Time</th>
                <th>Home</th>
                <th class="col-md-1"></th>
                <th class="col-md-1"></th>
                <th class="col-md-1"></th>
                <th>Away</th>
            </tr>
            {% for item in query_results %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ item.match_round }}</td>
                    <td>{{ item.match_date }}</td>
                    <td>{{ item.match_time }}</td>
                    <td>{{ item.home_team_name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ form.home_goals_predictions|add_class:"form-control"}}</td>
                    <td class="text-center">:</td>
                    <td>{{ form.away_goals_predictions|add_class:"form-control"}}</td>
                    <td>{{ item.away_team_name }}</td>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </table>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
    </form>        
{% endblock %}
```

This is works and displays the table excatly as I want.

However I am not able to extract the data as I want from it - to be more exact, when submiting the form, the data from the last row gets assigned to all the rows.

**views.py**

```
query_results = List.objects.all()
form = PredictionsForm()

if request.method == 'POST':
    form = PredictionsForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        user_prediction = form.save(commit = False)
        for result in query_results.all():
            for home_goals_predictions, away_goals_predictions in form.cleaned_data.items():
                user_prediction.id = result.id
                user_prediction.match_round = result.match_round
                user_prediction.home_team_name = result.home_team_name
                user_prediction.away_team_name = result.away_team_name
                user_prediction.user_id = request.user.id
                user_prediction.home_goals_predictions = form.cleaned_data['home_goals_predictions']
                user_prediction.away_goals_predictions = form.cleaned_data['away_goals_predictions']
                user_prediction.save()
        return redirect('/matches/')
    else:
        return redirect('/matches/')
else:
    template = loader.get_template('matches/input.html')
    context = {
        'query_results': query_results,
        'form': form
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

**forms.py**

```
class PredictionsForm(forms.ModelForm):
home_goals_predictions = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'cols': 1, 'rows': 1, 'maxlength': '2'}))
away_goals_predictions = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'cols': 1, 'rows': 1, 'maxlength': '2'}))

class Meta:
    model = Predictions
    fields = ('home_goals_predictions', 'away_goals_predictions')
```

I would really appreciate the help, as I am stuck on this problem and cannot figure out correct solution using formset/for loop.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure what's going on in your code since I can't see the definition of query_results but I'm pretty sure that what you are looking for is formsets. In short, a form submit's one thing / record. A formset is as the name suggest a set of forms, see [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/formsets/) for a full example. Also take a look at [modelformsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#django.forms.models.BaseModelFormSet), depending on your usecase this might really come in handy as well.

Edit:

Yeah so I would definitely go the modelformset route. Here's a short example of what that would like

in your views.py (the GET request).

```
from django.forms import modelformset_factory

ListFormSet = modelformset_factory(List, form=ListForm, extra=0)
list_formset = ListFormSet(queryset=List.objects.all())
```

Then during POST you can just do

```
ListFormSet = modelformset_factory(List, form=ListForm, extra=0)
list_formset = ListFormSet(request.POST, queryset=List.objects.all())

if list_formset.is_valid():

    for list_form in list_formset:

        list_form.save()
```

analogue to how a normal single form works.

Then in your template

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">

    {{ list_formset.management_form }}

    {% for list_form in list_formset %}
        ...
        {{ list_form.instance.match_round }}
        ...
        {{ list_form.home_goals_predictions }} #formfield
        {{ list_form.away_goals_predictions }} #formfield

    {% endfor %}

</form>
```

As you can see it is possible to access the query data via .instance

note: I typed this from memory so you might have to debug some typo's.

Comment: Edited the question with query_results definition, it just lists all the data from one table.

Comment: Also added forms.py and form variable definiton for more context